# recover encrypted folder content after format

Tags: 12.04, encryption, ecryptfs

So i made a backup of my `HOME` folder before i formatted my computer. Now i am trying to access the files in my encrypted private folder but with no luck. What are the commands that i should run in this case? Should i copy paste it to my current `HOME` first?

I read about `ecryptfs-recover-private` is that what i' m looking for? I really don't want to loose this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved my problem `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private`